# R6: add function to main class

Tags: r, r6

I like the `set` function in R6 as it allows me to build the object more dynamically. I want to be able to start with a blank settings object in the `R6Class()$private$settings`, and then dynamically add to it when I have new objects and tests.

`set` overrides the object, I would like to append it, or add a new function, to instead update a feature, before calling `R6Class(..)$new`.
Is this possible, or should I approach this differently? I get the error message `Error in element %in% names(self$private) : object 'self' not found`, so I'm assuming its something to do with the environments?

```
library(R6)
# build R6 template
templateSettings <- R6::R6Class(classname = "Template",
                                lock_objects = FALSE)

# updating an object in the R6Class, specifically a settings list in $private
newSetting <- function(element = NULL, name, value){
  stopifnot(element %in% names(self$private))
  stopifnot(!name %in% names(self$private[[element]]))

  object <- list(value)
  names(object) <- name
  self$private[[element]] <- c(self$private[[element]], object)
  invisible()
}

# create a settings list to try and update
templateSettings$set("private", "settings", list())

# try to assign in to templateSetting, assigns, but environment doesn't match
# templateSettings$set
assign("newSetting", newSetting, envir = environment(templateSettings$set))
templateSettings$newSetting

# dynamically update a settings object private$settings to be 
# list(a=1, b=2). "Error in element %in% names(self$private) : object 'self' not found"
templateSettings$newSetting("settings", "a", 1)
templateSettings$newSetting("settings", "b", 2)
```

Cheers,
Jonny